# DevExpress XtraReporty Print Without any UI Interaction

Tags: devexpress, xtrareport

I am having some trouble trying to get a report to print from a service that does not allow UI interaction.

Currently I can do the following

```
Dim myReport As New MyXtraReport(myData)
myReport.CreateDocument()

'Then I attempt to do the following

DirectCast(myReport.PrintingSystem, PrintingSystem).Print
```

However nothing happens when I do this. I don't get any exceptions just no document is printed.

Calling
`myReport.Print()`

will print the correct document but with UI interaction. What am I missing or is this just not intended to be viable.

I have also tried using the `myReport.PritingSystem.ExecCommand(PrintDirectly)` but it also doesn't print anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to call the Report's Print method:

```
new XtraReport1().Print();
```

I've tried this and it works.  If it does not work, I suggest that you post a sample in the [support center](http://devexpress.com/support/center) and we will try to help you.

Comment: actually this completely misses the point of what I am trying to do as this calls a UI.

Comment: This method does not invoke an UI dialog and prints the report using the default printer.  It is possible that a printer shows an UI dialog when data is printed.  In this case, we cannot work around this problem.