# Print a report without preview view and without preview browser view

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, xtrareport

How can I print a report without the preview, and taking the default  local printer? 
I try to put this code lines, but does´nt work:

```
Dim rep As New XtraReport1()
rep.DataSource = DataSet
rep.CreateDocument()
rep.Print()
```

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [DevExpress XtraReporty Print Without any UI Interaction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660178/devexpress-xtrareporty-print-without-any-ui-interaction)

Comment: Hello, the question that you link is not exactly what I need, and Its not working with my code, but thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solve my problem with this code:**

```
Imports DevExpress.XtraReports.UI
Imports System.IO
Imports DevExpress.XtraPrinting
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Drawing

Partial Class TPV_Tickets
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim Report As New TicketTPV

       ' THIS IS TO TAKE THE DEFAULT LOCAL PRINT
        Dim instance As New Printing.PrinterSettings
        Dim DefaultPrinter As String = instance.PrinterName

        ' THIS IS TO PRINT THE REPORT
        Report.PrinterName = DefaultPrinter
        Report.CreateDocument()
        Report.PrintingSystem.ShowMarginsWarning = False
        Report.Print()

    End Sub
End Class
```